# How to change a let value while debugging in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging

I am trying to change a let value while I am in mid-debug on Xcode (Xcode 12). But, when I try this debugger command

```
expression isLongBoxRide = true
```

I get this error in the Xcode debugger terminal. "error: cannot assign to value: 'isLongBoxRide' is immutable isLongBoxRide = true" It won't let me change a let value while debugging. It works when I try to change a var. I am just curious if it is even possible to change a let value while debugging on Xcode. It would be really nice if that was possible.

Comment: You can define it as a variable, after complete the debugging process and testing change  it to "let" if don't require it as mutable value

Comment: Why would that be nice, if it is `let` declared it will never have any other value? You would debugging the program in a state it could never have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler might analyze the let constant at compile time and then optimize your code. For example, think of something like:

```
func x() -> String {
    let doit = false
    if (doit) {
        return "Yes"
    } else {
        return "No"
    }
}
// ...
let result = x()
```

A clever compiler will change this to

```
func x() -> String {
    return "Yes"
}
// ...
let result = x()
```

or even throw away the call of `x()` completely:

```
    let result = "Yes"
```

Hence, there is no `doit` constant at all, expecially there is no `return "No"` branch in your program any more.
This is an extreme example, and the compiler typically will do so only in release mode, but you can see that it's not *easy* to allow constants to be changed during debugging, because the compiler might have to revert some opimizations.

Comment: Furthermore things may get even more confusing when the REPL swift state differs from what lldb "sees" under the hood. It's a nasty route that may likely lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Ahh makes sense. Wish it could be, but I guess not. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know Let can not be changed, that the all purpose of let.
You are **Let**ting it have a constant value
if you want to change, use var to be a **var**iable

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK `let` and `var` are not just cosmetics for your code. It has involvement in physical memory management. The `let` constant are store in the heap, while `var` are in the stacks. It affects the access time. So you basically cannot change a let variable without breaking the memory stack.

What you can try is to use a `var` for DEBUG compilation and `let` for RELEASE with something like :

```
#if DEBUG
var foo: Bar
#else
let foo: Bar
#endif
```

Comment: `let` are stored in heap, while `var` in stack - do you have any documentation to back this up?